# Send dynamic array list to android alert set multi choice Items

Tags: android

I am trying send dynamic array list to android alert set multi choice items and also, I want to keep show the selected items as per the selected array list in android.

My code snippet:

```
 ArrayList<String> userItems = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] list1 = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"};

String[] list2 = {"a","b","c"};

 boolean[] itemsLength = new boolean[dynamiclist.length];
                    for(int i=0;i<userItems.size();i++) {
                        if (userItems.contains(dynamic[i])) {
                            itemsLength[i] = true;
                            Log.d("Modes","****Checked items");
                        }
                        else {
                            itemsLength[i] = false;
                            Log.d("Modes","***unChecked items");
                        }
                }
                AlertDialog.Builder itemBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ModesPage.this);
                itemBuilder.setTitle("Select Items");
                itemBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(list1, itemsLength, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            userItems.add(dynamic[pos]);
                        }else if(userItems.contains(dynamic[pos])){
                            userItems.remove(dynamic[pos]);
                        }

                    }
                });
                itemBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                itemBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String item = "";
                        for(String list:userItems){
                            item = item+list;
                        }
                        modeList.add(item);
                        btnItem.setText(String.valueOf(modeList));
                    }
                });
                itemBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = itemBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();
```

When i am trying to pass list2 getting array index bound exception like below

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
```

Note: Here dynamic list contains either list1 or list2.

Please anyone can guide me how to resolve this one

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the first two arguments to itemBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems() must be the same; in this case you have **list1** and **itemsLength**. Think of the first argument as all the options that must be shown and the second argument as a boolean array that indicates whether or not those have been selected. Hence, it would be only logical that you pass arrays that are of the same size. Here you must pass **dynamiclist** instead of **list1**.